# Calling ActivityViewController from Custom Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a custom cell for my TableView app.  The TableViewController is called "BlogView".  My custom cell has a few buttons on it, one being a share button.  I want to present a UIActivityViewController when one of the buttons is pressed.

In the header for my custom cell, I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) BlogView *myViewController;
```

In the custom cell, I have for layoutSubview:

```
self.commentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapCommentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.commentButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

For the selector didTapCommentButtonAction I have:

```
- (void)didTapCommentButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CommentButtonTAPPED");
    Mail *mail = [[Mail alloc]init];
    NSString *html = self.prayerObject[@"Request"];
    NSString *thetitle = [self.prayerObject[@"Title"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *thedate = self.prayerObject[@"dateMade"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM_dd_yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *theNewDate1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:thedate];
    NSString *theNewDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theNewDate1];

    mail.thehtml = html;
    self.nameofhtmlfile = [[[[@"http://www.iprayed4u.net/app/" stringByAppendingString:thetitle] stringByAppendingString:@"_"] stringByAppendingString:theNewDate] stringByAppendingString:@".html"];
    //  Reminder *thereminder = [[Reminder alloc] init];
    //thereminder.thehtml = html;
    //thereminder.thetitle = thetitle;
    //thereminder.thedate = thedate;

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:@[mail]];


    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,

                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,

                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypeMail,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint

                                              ];

    }
    else {

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,

                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,

                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypeMail,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint,
                                              UIActivityTypeAirDrop
                                              ];

    }

    NSLog(@"Test");
       [self.myViewController presentViewController: activityVC animated: YES completion: nil];

   }
```

In BlogView.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    self.theObject = object;

    // Configure the cell to show todo item with a priority at the bottom
    cell.profileName.text = object[@"Title"];
    cell.contentLabel.text = object[@"Request"];
    cell.firstName = object[@"FirstName"];
    cell.lastName = object[@"LastName"];
    cell.iostoken = object[@"DeviceID"];
    cell.request = object[@"Title"];
    cell.prayerObject = object;
    PFFile *thumbnail = object[@"ProfilePic"];
    cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon60x60@2x.png"];
    [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

        UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnailImage];

        cell.profilePic.image = thumbnailImage;

    }];
    NSString *dates = object[@"dateMade"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM_dd_yyyy"];
   NSDate *datefromstring = [formatter dateFromString:dates];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [formatter2 stringFromDate:datefromstring];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:15];
    UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:12];



    return cell;
}
```

I get no warnings or errors, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have any other code? I think you would need a property for your button inside of the custom cell class. Then perhaps you could add a selector to that property button. Inside the selector method you could launch the ActivityViewController

Comment: The presentViewController is inside the selector method that the button calls, @JoshEngelsma

Comment: What is myViewController, and what is avc? Do you create or get a reference to either of those?

Comment: @rdelmar myViewController is the TableViewController, as I mentioned in my first sentence.  avc is the UIActivityViewController

Comment: So, how are you getting a reference to myViewController?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma added the code.  I am getting a reference to myViewController my setting a property in the header for it.

Comment: is self.commentButton an IBOutlet? also, is this a static tableview vc or a dynamic tableview vc?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma Dynamic.  Not IBOutlet, all done programmatically.

Comment: Declaring a property in the header file does not get you a reference to your controller; it only creates a pointer that doesn't yet point to anything. If you don't understand that, then you need to get yourself a book on Objective-C programming and read it.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive comment that points out I didn't do it right but provides nothing other than go buy a book to help me out.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @rdelmar is correct, your misunderstanding here is that you are declaring a property but it has not connection to the button in the view

Comment: Can you post the cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod, I think I have an idea how we can fix this

Comment: Yes @JoshEngelsma, it should be up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step one:** obtain an IBOutlet from the button on your cell to the CustomCell.h file...

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *commentButton;
```

**Step two:** In the cellForRowAtIndexPath, add a selector to the button on each cell and dress it up how you wanted it...**NOTICE** we are adding the selector to each 'cell button' now... not self.commentButton

```
[cell.commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapCommentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.commentButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.commentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

**Step three:** implement the selector method inside of the BlogView.m file rather than inside of the CustomCell.m

Comment: That did it.  I'm still new to custom cells and putting buttons on them so it was driving me nuts.  I had googled for 3 hours looking for similar issues, and closest I found was someone who said reference parent controller, and that was marked as accepted with no other text.

Comment: Awesome man! glad everything works! do you understand what your mistake was? Basically you were thinking that the button in the view was connected to your UIButton property... but it was not without setting up an IBOutlet first

Comment: Yea, has been a long 36 hours of coding almost, so starting to get a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Good times my friend, grab some coders food and keep at it! Happy coding :)

Comment: Ok, I thought I had this solved, but I found a bug on this...it's showing the UIActivityViewController, but the data it is passing, is only from the first row of the table.  I click it and it is supposed to pass a key from the object that populates one cell, but it does the same cell for each one.

Comment: Here's what I would do... set the tag of each button to the index path row in cellForRowAtIndexPath method... eg. cell.commentButton.tag = indexPath.row ... Then in your didTapCommentButton you can get the correct object by saying self.objects[sender.tag] ... assuming you are extending PFTableViewController and have access to the property self.objects